# How to do a super record entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to do one super record class with all of my commons methods:

```
class BaseRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
def initialize

 end


def self.search_by_filter(parameters)
  filter = []

  parameters.each do |key, param|
    if self.attributes.has_key?(key)
      filter[key] = param
    end
  end

  self.where(filter)    
end
```

but when i use this subclass,

```
class Item < BaseRecord
end
```

and i use the class on a controller, as the methods of super class, as just only method of the ActiveRecord like when ( Item.when(:name => "item) ) , the Record doesn't work, just say table base_record doesn't exits. Only method of ActiveRecord doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord is not designed to work with subclasses, at least not in the way you would expect. Subclassing in ActiveRecord is reserved for certain types of patterns, such as STI (Single Table Inheritance).

You can achieve the result with subclassing, but it would require to [declare the `BaseRecord` as abstract](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html).

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

My suggestion is to prefer composition using mixin. Define a custom module, such as

```
module Searchable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def search_by_filter(parameters)
      filter = []

      parameters.each do |key, param|
        if self.attributes.has_key?(key)
          filter[key] = param
        end
      end

      self.where(filter)    
    end
  end
end
```

and include it in the classes you want to extend such behavior.

```
class Item < BaseRecord
  include Searchable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement it as an abstract class:

```
class BaseRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses of BaseRecord will store records in the `base_records` table (by default). You do not need an `items` table in your case.